# Open Source Puppet Upgrade from 3.8.7 on Ubuntu OS

Tags: validation, syntax, ubuntu-16.04, puppet, puppetlabs-apache

I am in the process of upgrading Open Source Puppet from Server version 3.8.7 (which is hosted on Ubuntu 14.04 ) to a New version of Puppet on Ubuntu 16.04.

i have listed all the existing modules in current version however deciding which Open Source version to be chosen for upgrade is not very clear from documentations.

Hence,request help on 
  how to choose Next version of puppet server on Ubuntu 16.04?
  Can we upgrade straight from 3.x to 5.x or 6.x?

Anyone who has done this kind of upgrade, please share your learnings which can 
 support us to complete the safe upgrade.

Comment: This is a really, really broad question. You should probably break this down into sequential questions.

Comment: Is "5.3.x" a typo?  The latest in the Puppet 5 series is 5.5.8.

Comment: In any case, Puppet employs semantic versioning, so changes of major version number accompany breaking software changes.  There are breaking changes between Puppet 3 and Puppet 4, between Puppet 4 and Puppet 5, and between Puppet 5 and Puppet 6.  It's impossible for us to guess how affected you will be, but it's unlikely that you will be *un*affected.

Comment: @JohnBollinger , yes it was a typo and corrected it. Thank you

Comment: @MattSchuchard, I have edited the question and simplified.